# Import Text in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am working on my personal website, and I would like to display an expanded form of my cover letter in the middle of the page. Is there a way to import the contexts of a `.txt` file into a Vue component? The contents is static, so I would like for it to occur at compile time so that it is wrapped in a `<p>` or `<div>` tag in the HTML.

Comment: try to read this https://forum.vuejs.org/t/importing-text-file-as-string-in-vue-cli-3/37784

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it working from that link, and have submitted an answer with my solution.

Answer (score 3):

I was able able to get the text imported by using the contents of the link shared in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60516748/import-text-in-vue-js?noredirect=1#comment107060046_60516748).

What I did was install the `raw-loader` webpack package from NPM, then in my component, I import the text as a string, split the string by double newlines, and pass that in the data property function. In the template, I was able to iterate over the array I created with the `split()`, and generate `<span>`'s for each paragraph.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>
      <span class="pg" v-for="paragraph in letter" :key="paragraph">
          {{paragraph}}
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Letter from 'raw-loader!./assets/letter.txt'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: function () {
      return {
          letter: Letter.split("\n\n")
      }
  },
  components: {
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
.pg {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I tried that but get message: This dependency was not found: * raw-loader!./assets/test.txt

Comment: @bartburkhardt check the anwser again. "What I did was install the raw-loader webpack package from NPM"